# ng-repeat items only appear after pagination click

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, pagination, real-time, mean-stack

I'm new to the Javascript-Meanstack and I wanted to implement a project with my friends. We currently work on a network sniffer which should implement d3.js. We want to draw network traffic graphically. The app also uses the [pcap-module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pcap) from npm. We also use MongoDB for the database and the structure of the whole app was designed with the yeoman generator (generator -> http://meanjs.org/generator.html). (I am currently developing in german so please don't wonder if the variable names are weird!)

Currently we're able to save our packets into our database by creating a session for them. Code is available in **/server.js**.

```
pcap = require('pcap'),
pcap_session = pcap.createSession('en1', 'ip');
```

after requiring the pcap module we are saving the packets into our collection named also **packets**, with this code also in **/server.js**.

```
mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/scream-dev');

var packetSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    any: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed
});
var Pakete = mongoose.model('packets', packetSchema);

pcap_session.on('packet', function (raw_packet) {
    var packet_ip = pcap.decode.packet(raw_packet);

    var paket = new Pakete({
        any: packet
    });

    paket.save(function (err, paket) {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        //console.log('Saved a IP Packet!');
    });
    //console.log(packet_ip);
});
```

all nice at the moment, if we look into our packet-collection I will find (after enough time, a few!!) datapackets with this scheme:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5534c9c538ebe8617b5ae35c"),
    "any" : {
        "link_type" : "LINKTYPE_ETHERNET",
        "pcap_header" : {
            "tv_sec" : 1429522885,
            "tv_usec" : 846102,
            "caplen" : 145,
            "len" : 145
        },
        "payload" : {
            "dhost" : {
                "addr" : [ 
                    104, 
                    168, 
                    109, 
                    69, 
                    154, 
                    194
                ]
            },
            "shost" : {
                "addr" : [ 
                    164, 
                    147, 
                    76, 
                    194, 
                    149, 
                    78
                ]
            },
            "ethertype" : 2048,
            "vlan" : null,
            "payload" : {
                "version" : 4,
                "header_length" : 5,
                "header_bytes" : 20,
                "diffserv" : 0,
                "total_length" : 131,
                "identification" : 10167,
                "flags" : {
                    "reserved" : 0,
                    "df" : 0,
                    "mf" : 0
                },
                "fragment_offset" : 0,
                "ttl" : 51,
                "protocol" : 6,
                "header_checksum" : 56601,
                "saddr" : {
                    "o1" : 173,
                    "o2" : 194,
                    "o3" : 122,
                    "o4" : 22
                },
                "daddr" : {
                    "o1" : 192,
                    "o2" : 168,
                    "o3" : 154,
                    "o4" : 35
                },
                "protocol_name" : null,
                "payload" : {
                    "sport" : 443,
                    "dport" : 51541,
                    "seqno" : 4050575809,
                    "ackno" : 3439177583,
                    "data_offset" : 8,
                    "header_bytes" : 32,
                    "reserved" : 0,
                    "flags" : {
                        "cwr" : 0,
                        "ece" : 0,
                        "urg" : 0,
                        "ack" : 1,
                        "psh" : 1,
                        "rst" : 0,
                        "syn" : 0,
                        "fin" : 0
                    },
                    "window_size" : 1653,
                    "checksum" : 55427,
                    "urgent_pointer" : 0,
                    "options" : {
                        "mss" : null,
                        "window_scale" : null,
                        "sack_ok" : null,
                        "sack" : null,
                        "timestamp" : 973486614,
                        "echo" : 1190534572
                    },
                    "data" : { "$binary" : "FwMDAEoAAAAAAAABDDepuDqq89CSU3Qi2+AY8FFmXoNq4uSCD0e34q7nOEZVJ1+0RLj8JAEw30z5p8wEj    fBgaFzbgBWn3z9LA5CmySlNDg==", "$type" : "00" },
                    "data_bytes" : 79
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Everything's good. Now we want to add the datapackets, **first of all only with `ng-repeat` inside tables**, to our frontend. we also want to add a search, which searches in **EVERY** column of the table. pagination is also added in experimental way.

In our modules folder **/public/modules/network** (network is our own module) the **/public/modules/network/controllers/network.client.controller.js** is written like this:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('network').factory('Packets', ['$resource',
 function ($resource) {
    return $resource('network/:packetId', {
        packetId: '@_id'
    }, {
        update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        }
    });
 }
]);

angular.module('network')
    .controller('NetworkController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Packets',
     function ($scope, $stateParams, $location, Authentication, Packets) {


            $scope.authentication = Authentication;

            $scope.packets = Packets.query();

            $scope.filteredTodos = [];
            $scope.currentPage = 1;
            $scope.numPerPage = 16;
            $scope.maxSize = 20;
            $scope.todos = [];
            $scope.todos = $scope.packets;

            $scope.$watch('currentPage + numPerPage', function () {
                var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage),
                    end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;

                $scope.filteredTodos = $scope.todos.slice(begin, end);
             });
```

if i guessed it right, the ng-repeat code, like in our **/public/modules/network/views/network.client.view.html** has to look like this, according to the **Packet.query()** - Codeline, or is it?:

```
<div data-ng-controller="NetworkController">
<div>
    <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="id" custom-sort order="'id'" sort="sort">Object Id&nbsp;</th>
                <th class="name" custom-sort order="'name'" sort="sort">saddr&nbsp;</th>
                <th class="description" custom-sort order="'description'" sort="sort">daddr&nbsp;</th>
                <th class="field3" custom-sort order="'field3'" sort="sort">protocol&nbsp;</th>
                <th class="field4" custom-sort order="'field4'" sort="sort">sport&nbsp;</th>
                <th class="field5" custom-sort order="'field5'" sort="sort">dport&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in filteredTodos track by item.id | filter:search">
                <td>{{item._id}}</td>
                <td>{{item.any.payload.payload.saddr.o1}}.{{item.any.payload.payload.saddr.o2}}.{{item.any.payload.payload.saddr.o3}}.{{item.any.payload.payload.saddr.o4}}</td>
                <td>{{item.any.payload.payload.daddr.o1}}.{{item.any.payload.payload.daddr.o2}}.{{item.any.payload.payload.daddr.o3}}.{{item.any.payload.payload.daddr.o4}}</td>
                <td>{{item.any.payload.payload.protocol_name}}</td>
                <td>{{item.any.payload.payload.payload.sport}}</td>
                <td>{{item.any.payload.payload.payload.dport}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <pagination ng-model="currentPage" total-items="todos.length" max-size="maxSize" boundary-links="true">
        </pagination>
        <br>
        <input type="text" ng-model="search.$" />
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

we have figured out that if **track by item._id** is added in the **tablerow** element on the above code, the search doesnt work completely, if **track by..** is away its working partially (we couldnt filter a dot "." ??)

Anyway... we have two questions now:

First:
Why does the table only show results if we click on another pagenumber? (the pageumbers itself are refreshing continously)

Second:
How can we display a d3.js graph on the same page like our table is? We have installed **d3** and **nvd3** with `bower install --save`, also added the dependencies in **/config/env/all.js** like "**'public/lib/d3/d3.min.js'**" or "**'public/lib/d3/d3.js'**". Inside our /public/config.js we added also '**d3**' and '**nvd3**' to our applicationModuleVendorDependencies but it always returns an error:

> Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'd3' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

We also have tried to use a directive inside the controller but then it returns another error:

> Unknown Provider <- d3 <- d3BarsProvider

It would be really nice if you can help me with any code or ideas. We are working on this issue for weeks now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, according to the [`ng-repeat` documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat):

> if filters are used in the expression, they should be applied before the tracking expression.

Thus your expression becomes:

```
item in filteredTodos | filter:search track by item.id
```

Secondly, the D3 library is exposed on `window`. It is not part of Angular. You have three options:

1. Use D3 directly, without injection.
2. Inject `$window` like so: `function ($window) { var d3 = $window.d3; }`
3. Provide it yourself, like: `angular.module('yourApp').constant('d3', d3);`

I would recommend #3 because it's easier to mock in unit tests.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! I am wondering why it searches like "8" & "0" and not like "80" but thats another thing.

I will try now those three solutions to get it working. Just one question: Ive decided to follow your opinion, it look like this directive inside the controller:

angular.module('network')
    .directive('d3Bars', function ($window) {
        return {...
            },
            link: function (..., $window) {
                var d3 = $window.d3;
...
also needs "_" in the code.
i guess this is lodash or underscore?
if i try to it gets "_" is not defined and i cant import

Comment: You cannot inject in `link` function. You already have `$window` in your directive function. Just use it normally: `link: function (scope, element) { var d3 = $window.d3; }`.

Comment: so i have to inject the underscore module in the directive function? i dont understand how to add a (frontend?) module into this directive ... you really helped me out with the $window, now it shows at least the inputs for the graphics, now just "_" is not defined ..

EDIT: link function done, works, thanks only underscore needed now

Comment: Well, if `_` (underscore or lodash) is undefined, you need to install it (with bower), include in your app and provide it in the same way as you did with d3 (neither lodash nor underscore are part of Angular).

Comment: I installed it with "bower install underscore --save", added the file-dependencies in "/config/all.js" and "/config/production.js" ...

I need it also in my controller for randomize function:

$scope.randomize = function () {
                $scope.set.x = ..
                $scope.set.y = ..
                _.times($scope.n, function (n) {
                    ..code
                });
            };

so i simply dont understand how to add it in controller AND directive :(

by the way adding dependencies in /public/config.js is wrong, isnt it? otherwise ill get "Module not found .."

Comment: Inject `_` in your controller, and in your directive, and everywhere else you need it.

Comment: I tried but now it throws another error message and the graph doesnt appear ..
Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'times' of undefined.
"_.times($scope.n, function (n) {" uses the _ ,
was it right implemented?:
".controller('NetworkController', ['$scope', '...', function ($scope, ... , _) {"
and the directive: ".directive('d3Bars', function ($window, _) {"